# Is it possible to set the compiling and linking flags in Makefile.am instead of configure.ac?

Tags: compilation, linker, autotools, dynamic-linking, ldflags

Is it possibleto set such flags in Makefile.am instead? That will solve the problem I asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617744/how-to-disable-the-runtime-checking-of-dynamic-libraries-if-they-are-not-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Autoconf and Automake, then you should be able to pass in linker flags at compile time to make using the following:

```
make LDFLAGS='-L/my/nonstandard/prefix/lib' target
```

Additionally, you can do this for CC, CFLAGS, CPP, CPPFLAGS, and LIBS. For example:

```
make CC=gcc-4.2 \
    LIBS='-lmylibrary -lhislib ../lib/libcustom.a' \
    LDFLAGS='-L/opt/vend/lib' \
    CPPFLAGS='-I../include' \
    CFLAGS='-Wall' \
    target
```

If you want to make them permanent in the make file, add them the to automake variables:

```
AM_LIBS     = -lmylibrary -lhislib ../lib/libcustom.a
AM_LDFLAGS  = -L/opt/vend/lib
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I../include
AM_CFLAGS   = -Wall
```

Using the above variables, will still allow you to add flags by passing them to make using the previous method.

Comment: `AM_LIBS` doesn't exist.

Comment: prog_LDADD do the job in the place of AM_LIBS that seems to not exist everywhere.

Comment: @DanielKO With a basic Makefile.am, you are correct, however just add the lines to the Makefile.am before your target macros.

Answer (score 2):

Some linkers have options to ignore unresolved symbols at link time - as long as you're certain the library will be available at *load* time. e.g., For [GNU ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options), there's: `--unresolved-symbols`, where an option like: `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` might be appropriate. The OS X (Mach-O) linker has: `-undefined <error|warning|suppress|dynamic_lookup>`

When running a program, all symbols *must* be resolved by the dynamic linker / loader.

This shouldn't be confused with [*dynamic loading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) facilities, which require you to load libraries at runtime, and fetch a function pointer or handle for a given function name.

For the program `'prog'`, you can add extra flags to `prog_LDFLAGS` in `Makefile.am`.